# Windows bootloader broke grub. boot is broken (can't remove?)

Tags: grub2

I installed ubuntu over windows a while ago on a laptop. I haven't needed windows for the past 6 months but I finally need to boot into it. In grub, I selected the Windows 10 option, and windows went through its bootloader and eventually hung. On restarting the machine grub went into rescue mode, and I went to a live CD to rescue.

/boot is completely broken. I can't even rm it, here's what it looks like:

```
ls -l /
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root        7 Dev 27 13:15 bin -> usr/bin
d?????????    ? ?    ?           ?            ? boot
....
```

`rm /boot` gives me `cannot remove 'boot': Bad message`. grub-install can't find the /boot directory to fix grub.

Is there any way out of this? Fortunately it looks like the rest of the filesystem is intact so worst case I can backup and restore, but I would like to avoid if possible

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. And Windows often turns fast start up back on, which prevents grub from booting it. You may need your Windows repair/recovery flash drive. Boot-Repair cannot fix most Windows issues, but report shows most issues. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred this is a grub issue, not a windows issue. If there is a windows issue that's something I'll deal with down the road